# Refusal of a UK visit visit visa due to unexplained deposits. How to re apply?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have applied for UK standard visitor visa to attend my graduation ceremony for the Postgraduate course which i have completed last year. I have submitted the invitation letter from university, flight reservation, educational certificates, hotel booking. My uncle is funding my trip i have attached his banks statement and affidavit of financial support, he is funding because  i have opened bank account two months ago so according to UKVI policy banks statements should be for last six months so for that reason i have attached my statement as well to show the proof that why my uncle is funding my trip and still got rejected. Kindly please help me related to this problem and after how many days i should re apply again and what documents i should provide because my graduation ceremony will be held on 20th July 2017.

> **THE DECISION**
>
> I Have refused your application for visit visa because i am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph V 4.2 - V4.10.
>   of appendix V: Immigration rules for visitor because:
>
> ⦁ You have applied for a visa to visit the United Kingdom for 2 weeks. I have considered your application against paragraphs V4.2 - V
>   4.10.
>
> ⦁ I note that you have previously travelled to the united Kingdom, and with your earlier application provided full details to satisfy the
>   Entry Clearance Officer (ECO) at that time that you had met the
>   requirements of the immigration Rules as a visitor; however each case
>   must be decided on its individual merits at the time of application.
>
> ⦁ You state you wish to visit the UK to attend your graduation ceremony held on 18/07/2017 at ABC University. I note you have
>   provided a letter from the University. Whilst i acknowledge this
>   invite, I must be satisfied with your overall personal circumstances
>   and intentions.
>
> ⦁ You state in your application you are a Voluntary/ Unpaid worker. In support of your application you have provided your bank
>   statement. However the documents you have provided do not demonstrate
>   you are involved in any volunteering or unpaid work and as such it is
>   not clear how you are now financially supported in Pakistan. You have
>   submitted a bank statement from BARC  with a latest balance of 700
>   pounds. However there are a number of unexplained cash deposits into
>   the account throughout which are not sourced and it is not clear where
>   these funds originate from. You state your uncle will cover your cost
>   of 1500 pounds towards your trip. I note you have provided a letter
>   from him, a copy of passport and his bank statement. However the
>   documents do not demonstrate his employment circumstances or his
>   monthly income. It is therefore not clear where the 2900 pounds held
>   in his bank account originate from. As such, without evidence of the
>   origin of this money, i am not satisfied that is genuinely yours and
>   available to fund the proposed visit. I have considered the evidence
>   and information submitted in your application but i am not satisfied
>   that you have accurately presented your circumstances and therefore
>   your intentions in applying to enter the UK. This undermines the
>   credibility of your application to the extent that i am not satisfied
>   that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or intend to leave
>   the UK at the end of your visit. **Paragraph V4.2(a) (c) (e)**
>
> **Future applications**
>
> Any future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their individual merits, however you are likely to be refused unless
>   the circumstances of your application change.
>
> In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to administrative review.

Comment: It would appear that what you need is a well-paid, stable job to return to. Right now, they are not satisfied of your *intent* to leave the UK again. Getting a stable job in two weeks would be all but impossible.

Comment: I am doing an internship currently which will finish in August, if i get a letter from company will it be enough to make my application strong?

Comment: I doubt that it will be enough by itself. An internship is not a stable job.

Comment: What if i have an offer letter for a job, what should i mention in application that i am unemployed or employed cause i will join in august

Comment: Any new application without a substantial change in circumstances risks a new refusal. I don't *think* an offer letter will be enough.

Comment: main refusal was due to the unexplained funds and lack of evidence of supporting documents and i m ready to provide all the documents they need